# Creating methods to update & save documents with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, methods, express, mongoose

After checking out the [official documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics), I am still not sure on how to create methods for use within `mongoose` to create & update documents.

So how can I do this?

I have something like this in mind:

```
mySchema.statics.insertSomething = function insertSomething () {
    return this.insert(() ?
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Methods are used to to interact with the current instance of the model. Example:

```
var AnimalSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
  , type: String
});

// we want to use this on an instance of Animal
AnimalSchema.methods.findSimilarType = function findSimilarType (cb) {
  return this.find({ type: this.type }, cb);
};

var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', AnimalSchema);
var dog = new Animal({ name: 'Rover', type: 'dog' });

// dog is an instance of Animal
dog.findSimilarType(function (err, dogs) {
  if (err) return ...
  dogs.forEach(..);
})
```

Statics are used when you don't want to interact with an instance, but do model-related stuff (for example search for all Animals named 'Rover').

If you want to insert / update an instance of a model (into the db), then `methods` are the way to go. If you just need to save/update stuff you can use the `save` function (already existent into Mongoose). Example:

```
var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', AnimalSchema);
var dog = new Animal({ name: 'Rover', type: 'dog' });
dog.save(function(err) {
  // we've saved the dog into the db here
  if (err) throw err;

  dog.name = "Spike";
  dog.save(function(err) {
    // we've updated the dog into the db here
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

Comment: But how could I do `dog.save()` from within a method?

Comment: `this.save()`, since `this` would refer to `dog`

Comment: @alessioalex - I notice this is similar to the example inthe mongoose docs, however they respecify the type like : `return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);`  I've never understood why we have to use `model('Animal')` here, as we are adding this method to the Animal schema.  Presumably it's optional then - do you know why it's written like this in the docs?

Comment: You use `mongoose.model('Animal', AnimalSchema)` to register the schema and then later in your code elsewhere `mongoose.model('Animal')` to grab the model again. When you add something to the model you add it to the schema like `AnimalSchema.methods.isCat` or `AnimalSchema.statics.findAllDogs`.

Answer (score 59):

From inside a static method, you can also create a new document by doing :

```
schema.statics.createUser = function(callback) {
  var user = new this();
  user.phone_number = "jgkdlajgkldas";
  user.save(callback);
};
```

Comment: I ended up doing this too - something bothers me about creating a new this() though, and I'm not sure what to do about that. Does anyone else have a nice way to do this?

Comment: if you have:
var model=bla bla before the static, you can do new model() inside of it, as it's within reach

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one thing in my case : if you try to use `this` within a mongoose query, it'll point the `this` of this query, not the `this` of the static instance. That was my problem.

Comment: yeah, you can't use 'this' as intended instead a static method :) hydrozen's answer will be incorrect. new this() is ok, but in this case 'this' will point to the wrong object.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you need to create a function that calls .save(). Anything that you need to do before the model is saved can be done using [.pre()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

If you want the check if the model is being created or updated do a check for this.isNew()